# stringWithFormat and NSArray

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSArray with objects :

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Saturday",@"Sunday",@"Monday",@"tuesday",@"Wednesday",@"thursday",nil];
```

and some times like this :

```
array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Tuesday",@"Monday",nil];
```

I would like to have a string like this :

```
dinner : sunday, monday,tusday, wednesday, thurs...
```

or

```
dinner : tuesday, monday.
```

How i can i do this with stringWithFormat?

thanks

Comment: sorry, i am not good in english

Comment: your english is fine, you asked a good question.  One thing to note, in your example you use a handful of uppercase letters when adding to the array, @"Sunday"  but your display uses all lower case names: 'sunday'.  If you really want all lowercase names to display you can do string = [string lowercaseString]; After the calls to componentsJoinedByString mentioned below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `NSArray`'s `componentsJoinedByString:`.

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Saturday",@"Sunday",@"Monday",@"tuesday",@"Wednesday",@"thursday",nil];
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dinner: %@", [array componentsJoinedByString:@", "]];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dinner: %@",[array componentsJoinedByString:@","]];
```